# jQuery: count the JSON objects stored in localstorage?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm creating a JSON string and store it in the localstorage. I'm basically creating a simple shopping cart using only jQuery.

I'm now trying to count the objects in the JSON in the localstorage BUT the I'm not getting anything at all.

I've created this fiddle which explains the issue live:

https://jsfiddle.net/zmbpk1tr/

This is the code:

```
  var data = JSON.stringify(json);
  var numberOfElements = data.id.length;
  alert(numberOfElements);
```

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have an error in `var numberOfElements = data.id.length;` you need to get the length from data not from the id :

```
var numberOfElements = data.length;
```

and you need to replace `JSON.stringify(json);` with var `$.parseJSON(json);`

https://jsfiddle.net/zmbpk1tr/3/

Comment: that is still returning a wrong number! I've only got `1 Object` in the JSON but the `alert(numberOfElements);` is returning `35`.

Comment: nice one Mostafa. although I've changed my strategy but your answer should hopefully help others in the future.